# How to Assert that an ASP.NET control has the correct AccessKey using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm currently converting old tests written in C# from NUnit with ASPTester to MSTest with Selenium.
Some of the tests check that the access keys of controls are correct using:

```
Assert.AreEqual("A", control.AccessKey);
```

(For anyone who doesn't know, Access keys allow users to press ALT + another Key to jump focus to a specific control on the ASP page.)

My issue is finding a way to easily do this using WebDriver.
Obviously this can be done manually by invoking the Key presses and then asserting that the control is in focus, but I feel like there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the access key is an attribute in the client page then:

```c#
element = driver.FindElementById("Namebox");
Assert.AreEqual("A", element.GetAttribute("accesskey"));
```